# Android: How to call ndk function from Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-ndk, kotlin

This code works on Java. But after migration to Kotlin, compiler higlits method  `native fun stringFromNative(): String` as error with  following text:

> Function without a body must be abstract

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Toast.makeText(this, stringFromNative(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

companion object {

    init {
        System.loadLibrary("_ndkkt")
    }
    native fun stringFromNative(): String
}
}
```

Thanks @KenVanHoeylandt!

Andswer is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Toast.makeText(this, stringFromNative(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

   init {
        System.loadLibrary("_ndkkt")
    }

    external fun getStringFromNative(): String
}

}
```

If you wish to use this native function in another class you can specify the class which encloses it as in:

```
val aStringFromNative : String = MainActivity().getStringFromNative()
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `native` with `external`?

Comment: Does it make a difference to put `native fun stringFromNative(): String` outside of the companion object and into the `MainActivity`?

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt Solved!Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put `external fun stringFromNative(): String` outside of the companion object and into the `MainActivity`.

(I found the answer by looking at https://github.com/ligee/kotlin-ndk-samples)

Answer (score 12):

```
Kotlin :

call method from ndk file
 external fun stringFromJNI(): String


 load c++ file
 companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written