# Using AssetManager class from Android NDK in a Flutter app

Tags: c++, flutter, android-ndk, oboe, dart-ffi

I've been trying to use the Android NDK's [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset#functions) class in my Flutter app, that works with [Google Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe), to access to audio files. Following [this](https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/RhythmGame) example in the Oboe repository, I learned that they obtain the `AssetManager` from Java like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_google_oboe_sample_rhythmgame_MainActivity_native_1onStart(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                                     jobject jAssetManager) {

    AAssetManager *assetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, jAssetManager);
    if (assetManager == nullptr) {
        LOGE("Could not obtain the AAssetManager");
        return;
    }

    game = std::make_unique<Game>(*assetManager);
    game->start();
}
```

Basically with the argument `jAssetManager` they pass from Java to the C++ functions, through the JNI interface. Now I'm not working with JNI because I'm using Flutter and Dart, and the way in Dart for communicating with C++ functions is through [dart:ffi](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop), but since the only way I can create an `AssetManager` is with `AAssetManager_fromJava(env, jAssetManager)`, I need those two arguments that I can't find a way to replace with Flutter and Dart.

I did some research and when I created the Flutter FFI plugin, apparently the Dart code communicates with Kotlin code, which then calls the native C++ functions.

Here's my C++ function:

```
EXTERNC void *engine_create(void) {
    AAssetManager *assetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, jAssetManager);   // ERROR: How do I get these?
    if (assetManager == nullptr) {
        LOGE("Could not obtain the AAssetManager");
        return nullptr;
    }   

    return new DSPAudioEngine(*assetManager);
}
```

Here's the Dart wrapper for that function:

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

typedef oboe_engine_init = Pointer<Void> Function();
typedef OboeEngineInit = Pointer<Void> Function();

class FfiGoogleOboe {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('ffi_google_oboe');

  static Future<String> get platformVersion async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }

  static FfiGoogleOboe _instance;

  factory FfiGoogleOboe() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = FfiGoogleOboe._();
    }
    return _instance;
  }


  OboeEngineInit _engineInit;

  FfiGoogleOboe._() {
    final oboeLib = DynamicLibrary.open('libffi_google_oboe.so');

    _engineInit = oboeLib
        .lookup<NativeFunction<oboe_engine_init>>('engine_create')
        .asFunction();
  }

}
```

And here's the Kotlin code I found in the FFI plugin implementation:

```
package g1_assd_2020.ffi_google_oboe

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar
import android.content.res.AssetManager

/** FfiGoogleOboePlugin */
public class FfiGoogleOboePlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  /// The MethodChannel that will the communication between Flutter and native Android
  ///
  /// This local reference serves to register the plugin with the Flutter Engine and unregister it
  /// when the Flutter Engine is detached from the Activity
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "ffi_google_oboe")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
  }

  // This static function is optional and equivalent to onAttachedToEngine. It supports the old
  // pre-Flutter-1.12 Android projects. You are encouraged to continue supporting
  // plugin registration via this function while apps migrate to use the new Android APIs
  // post-flutter-1.12 via https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration.
  //
  // It is encouraged to share logic between onAttachedToEngine and registerWith to keep
  // them functionally equivalent. Only one of onAttachedToEngine or registerWith will be called
  // depending on the user's project. onAttachedToEngine or registerWith must both be defined
  // in the same class.
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
      val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "ffi_google_oboe")
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(FfiGoogleOboePlugin())
    }
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

Finally, here's how the people from Oboe handle it using JNI and Java:

```
package com.google.oboe.sample.rhythmgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setDefaultStreamValues(this);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        native_onStart(getAssets());
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        native_onStop();
    }

    static void setDefaultStreamValues(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            AudioManager myAudioMgr = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            String sampleRateStr = myAudioMgr.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
            int defaultSampleRate = Integer.parseInt(sampleRateStr);
            String framesPerBurstStr = myAudioMgr.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
            int defaultFramesPerBurst = Integer.parseInt(framesPerBurstStr);

            native_setDefaultStreamValues(defaultSampleRate, defaultFramesPerBurst);
        }
    }

    private native void native_onStart(AssetManager assetManager);
    private native void native_onStop();
    private static native void native_setDefaultStreamValues(int defaultSampleRate,
                                                      int defaultFramesPerBurst);
}
```

Comment: I think your initial approach of loading the asset using RootBundle and then passing the bytes to C using ffi is far easier to get to work.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion. I wanted to eliminate the possibility of reading the files wrong (specially if the file was compressed like an mp3), and since I couldn't find a library in Dart to get PCM data from a ```.wav``` or an ```.mp3```, I wanted to follow Oboe's example. However I didn't find a way to do this with Flutter, so what I'm trying to do now is passing a buffer of bytes down to C++ using ```rootBundle```, and then decoding from there.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to reimplement the method 
```AAssetDataSource* newFromCompressedAsset(AAssetManager &assetManager, size_t len, AudioProperties *outputProperties);
``` 
to take a ```float* buffer``` instead of ```AAssetManager &assetManager```. The method I'm referring to is in [this](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/RhythmGame/src/main/cpp/audio/AAssetDataSource.h) file, line 31.

Comment: getting PCM from a WAV in Dart is easy, mp3 not so much, so you'll want to use AMediaCodec probably with a custom data source backed by your asset bytes. See: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#amediaextractor_setdatasourcecustom and https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/RhythmGame/src/main/cpp/audio/NDKExtractor.cpp

Comment: That NDKExtractor is exactly what I'm trying to replicate right now, but with a ```float* buffer``` instead of an ```AAsset* asset```. If I manage to do it, I'll try to post an answer with the code.

Comment: You would want a uint_8 buffer as the input, not floats, as that's what you'll read from the asset and pass across using ffi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to pass the AssetManager reference from your plugin's Kotlin file to the C++ library. This answer explains how to make the Kotlin file call C++ code: [Android: How to call ndk function from Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932662/android-how-to-call-ndk-function-from-kotlin)

You'll want to use a methodChannel call to trigger this. You can get the AssetManager reference in the onAttachedToEngine method from `flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext.assets`.

Here's an example Flutter plugin that reads an asset in a C++ library:
https://github.com/mikeperri/ndk_asset_manager_example/commit/533d28b33c1d22f89028f89691f78e907bf19db3